Frama-C with Coq interactive prover
I am trying to run Frama-C on a small code sample.
It works pretty well:
# frama-c -wp bubble_sort.c              
[kernel] Parsing bubble_sort.c (with preprocessing)
[wp] Warning: Missing RTE guards
[wp] bubble_sort.c:15: Warning: 
  Missing assigns clause (assigns 'everything' instead)
[wp] bubble_sort.c:8: Warning: 
  Missing assigns clause (assigns 'everything' instead)
[wp] 13 goals scheduled
[wp] [Timeout] typed_bubble_sort_ensures (Qed 1ms) (Alt-Ergo)
[wp] [Timeout] typed_bubble_sort_terminates_part2 (Qed 1ms) (Alt-Ergo)
[wp] [Timeout] typed_bubble_sort_loop_invariant_established (Qed 2ms) (Alt-Ergo)
[wp] [Timeout] typed_bubble_sort_loop_invariant_4_established (Qed 2ms) (Alt-Ergo)
[wp] Proved goals:   10 / 14
  Unreachable:       1
  Qed:               7
  Alt-Ergo 2.5.4:    2 (17ms-20ms)
  Timeout:           4
[wp:pedantic-assigns] bubble_sort.c:6: Warning: 
  No 'assigns' specification for function 'bubble_sort'.
  Callers assumptions might be imprecise.

So there remain 4 proof obligations to be proved.
I want to prove them with the Coq interactive prover.
I've found several options that all look obsolete/irrelevant.
How can I run Coq to prove those proof obligations?
# frama-c -version         
28.1 (Nickel)

Running on Macbook M3 (ARM64)
I didn't manage to run frama-c-gui.
I can run Ivette, but I understand that it doesn't support WP yet, right?
#frama-c-gui              
zsh: command not found: frama-c-gui

frama-c -plugins
Alias Analysis      Lightweight May-Alias Analysis (experimental) (-alias-h)
Aorai               verification of behavioral properties (experimental)
                    (-aorai-h)
Callgraph           automatically compute the callgraph of the program. Using
                    Eva might improve the precision of this plug-in (-cg-h)
Dive                An interactive imprecision graph generator for Eva.
                    (-dive-h)
Dominators          Compute postdominators of statements (-dominators-h)
E-ACSL              Executable ANSI/ISO C Specification Language --- runtime
                    assertion checker generator (-e-acsl-h)
Eva                 automatically computes variation domains for the
                    variables of the program (-eva-h)
From analysis       functional dependencies (-from-h)
Impact              impact analysis (-impact-h)
Inout               operational, imperative and all kinds of inputs/outputs
                    (-inout-h)
Instantiate         Overrides standard library functions (-instantiate-h)
Loop                Find maximum number of iterations in loops (-loop-h)
Markdown report     generates a report in markdown format (-mdr-h)
Metrics             syntactic metrics (-metrics-h)
Nonterm             Warns when definitively non-terminating functions/loops
                    are detected (e.g. reachable functions with unreachable
                    returns). (-nonterm-h)
Obfuscator          obfuscator for confidential code (-obfuscator-h)
Occurrence          automatically computes where variables are used
                    (-occurrence-h)
Pdg                 Program Dependence Graph (-pdg-h)
Postdominators      computing postdominators of statements
                    (-postdominators-h)
Reduction           Generate ACSL annotations from Eva information (-reduc-h)
Report              Properties Status Report (-report-h)
Rtegen              generates annotations for runtime error checking (-rte-h)
Scope               data dependencies higher level functions (-scope-h)
Security-slicing    security slicing (experimental, undocumented)
                    (-security-slicing-h)
Semantic constant folding  propagates constants semantically (-scf-h)
Server              Frama-C Request Server (experimental) (-server-h)
Server TypeScript API  Generate TypeScript API for Server (-server-tsc-h)
Slicing             code slicer (-slicing-h)
Sparecode           code cleaner (-sparecode-h)
Studia              Tools for Eva case studies (-studia-h)
Users               function callees (-users-h)
Variadic            Variadic functions translation (-variadic-h)
WP                  Proof by Weakest Precondition Calculus (-wp-h)


Indeed, Frama-C 28.1's Ivette has no WP support, but Frama-C 29's does: https://www.frama-c.com/fc-versions/copper.html
You can try opam update && opam install frama-c.29.0, and then run ivette (after installing nvm and running nvm use 20 and npm install --global yarn' to get the right version of node and yarn). The first run will be slow, it should download and install it, but work fine afterwards. You can also try getting the macOS binary and using it.

Thank you.
I've updated frama-c as you suggested and got the new version of ivette running.
I can see the WP integration and get the list of WP goals.
Apparently, it is running alt-ergo and/or z3 for trying to prove those goals automatically.
But I still cannot see how to use Coq for proving interactively the goals that were not proved by automatic provers
